# Python way to split a particular string in a specific list

Tags: python

Trying to get

```
x = 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE'
```

to

```
y = ['AAA-BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE']
```

is there a nice way to do this?

I'm not looking for a very general rule, I just wanna know how would you go around forming the above `y` having the `x`. It's basically a string of letters with a separator, and I want to get a list of all items incrementally like shown in the example. (if you can get `['AAA', 'AAA-BBB', 'AAA-BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE']` it doesn't really matter cause I can just split the list to cut how many elements I need to cut)

Comment: And by what rules does `x` become `y`, what is their relationship? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Yeah, but it's an ugly solution and I'm to embarrassed to post it

Comment: But it'd at least give us a clue as to how you think `y` should be formed from `x`. At the moment all we can do is guess. What happens when `x = 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE-FFF-GGG-HHH'`? Or `x = 'AAA'`? What are the variables here, the rules of conversion, what should happen in case something doesn't match the rules, etc.?

Comment: No need to be embarrassed, but you do need to explain the rules for the splitting procedure to us.

Comment: But I did. I'm just asking how would you form the ```y``` there from the ```x```. Not sure what else you asking me for

Comment: @confused00: right now just *using `y = ['AAA-BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE']`* fits your question. E.g. don't even look at `x`. Or perhaps you wanted `y = ['AAA-BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', x]`. That'd also satisfy your requirements.

Comment: How do you decide where to split? Do you split twice on `-` from the right side of the string, or do you keep splitting until there are only 2 `-` left in the string?

Comment: I edited it a bit. @MartijnPieters I want to get that ```y``` from the ```x``` though

Comment: @confused00: it is still far from clear; can the separator vary? Why don't you have `'AAA'` and `'AAA-BBB'` in `y`? We cannot read your mind here, you need to spell these things out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the separator is the one in the example and I addressed the latter question. I guess I'm just looking for an idea how people would do this, and then I'll generalise myself to fit all my cases

Comment: @confused00: then *add that to your question*. When you have to clarify a question in the comments, then it is important enough to add to the question itself. Comments are only ever meant to be temporary.

Comment: I guess. I just assumed that if I give no other details then someone would just help me with a solution that fits my case and nothing else, and I'd be fine generalising from there, rather than trying to give all the details/edge cases/scenarios in the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would proceed in two steps. First, split by the separator:

```
z = x.split('-')
```

Then, join each item from/to a certain length:

```
['-'.join(z[:i+1]) for i in range(2,len(z))]
```

If you don't want to hardcode `2`, and start from the middle, use things like `len(z)/2`, or another criteria:

```
>>> ['-'.join(z[:i+1]) for i in range(2,len(z))]
['AAA-BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE']
>>> ['-'.join(z[:i+1]) for i in range(len(z)/2,len(z))]
['AAA-BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE']
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Split, then join again, picking larger and larger slices:

```
elems = x.split('-')
['-'.join(elems[:i]) for i in xrange(3, len(elems) + 1)]
```

This assumes you want your first part to have 3 elements, always. The loop goes through `3`, `4` and `5`, slicing `elems` to that many elements and joins them together again on the separator.

Demo:

```
>>> x = 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE'
>>> elems = x.split('-')
>>> ['-'.join(elems[:i]) for i in xrange(3, len(elems) + 1)]
['AAA-BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD-EEE']
```

Comment: I just accepted the first reply that answered the question but I appreciate your help, thanks